# Creat list of list in the boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I want to create a list of list using `boost::python::list`.

I tried this code but it seems the sub list does not have append function!

```
boost::python::list array;
boost::python::list temp;


for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            array.append(temp);
            for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
            {
                array[i].append(0); //error! array[i] does not have "append" member
            }
        }
```

Error message:

```
error: ‘boost::python::api::object_item’ has no member named ‘append’
       distArray[i].append(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that the array does not have an `append` member. I tried your code but it does not work.

Comment: It looks like you need to use `Py_Initialize()` and `Py_Finalize()`, as in the above link.

Comment: Still I get errors:  `error: ‘boost::python::api::object_item’ has no member named ‘append’
       array[i].append<int>(0);`
                    
`error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
       array[i].append<int>(0);`

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This question is about list[index] returning a generic python object, rather than the type that was put in. The other question was about append to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append directly to temp.

```
boost::python::list array;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
    boost::python::list temp;
    for (int j = 0; j < max; j++){
        temp.append(0);
    }
    array.append(temp);
}
```

Since list can hold anything, you get back a generic object when you pull it back out as array[i]. In c++ you need to know the type. Just adding a typecast is enough to satisfy the compiler, but would be risky if anything else can get in there.  Boost python has conversion check functions if you need to work on the list later.